# Product page is not refreshing or updating. What am I missing?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I've tried everything I can find on the web about Magento 1.9 and refreshing a product page. I've updated the price and the old price is still displayed.

Things I've tried: - Hard refresh in browser - Different browser - Private browsing

I've refreshed the cache for all caches in the page "Cache Storage Management"
The Magento Cache has been flushed
The Cache Storage has been flushed
All indexes have been reindexed
Disable and re-enable combining CSS and JavaScript files.
I'm on the correct product page. Both the URL and the product ID match the page and the product in magento.

I've deleted all files in the "/var/cache" folder.

I've updated the product description by adding a period and other small stuff.

Yet the page stays the same. Every time I refresh it displays the old data.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to perform price reindex. You can try to do it from Magento Admin:

System -> Index Management -> Click on ***Reindex*** at "Product Prices" row.

If ***Index mode*** is ***Update on Save***, it should work out of the box. Otherwise, if it's ***Manual update***, you'll have to configure cron job which will call indexer on every X minutes.

You can try to reindex it from command line with:

```
php5 shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
```